# Proxy extensions for requests with a specific origin

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, proxy, webrequest

I need to write an extension for chrome. Which will be able to determine, based on the request origin, whether to go to the proxy or not. How to do it?

I read about webRequest, I read about chrome.proxy.settings, but I don’t understand how to cross them together